# gstreamer rtsp stream chance resolution

Tags: gstreamer, screen-resolution

I am new to Gstreamer and have a problem in changing the resolution of a videostream before displaying it. On a computer, running Windows 7, I receive a RTP/RTSP stream with a resolution of 320x184. I can display the stream by using the command:

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.0.0.3:554/stream1 latency=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink

A small window is presented showing the video stream, with no latency.
This is almost what I want to achieve. I only want to display this stream at a resolution of 1280 x 800, without a window border. I do not know how to extend the Gstreamer pipeline to achieve this. Can some of you help me out here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this from the command line. You need a write a real GUI application for this purpose. You will then have to interact your GStreamer pipeline with your GUI. To be more precise you will have to the tell the pipeline's renderer where to draw the video into. For this you will need the `GstVideoOverlay` interface.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-gstvideooverlay.html

There are also examples on how to use it:

https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/master/tests/examples/overlay

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question: adding videoscale did the trick.
The full command now looks like this:

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.0.0.3:554/stream1 latency=0 ! decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=800 ! autovideosink

Thanks for the input

Comment: By the way: This solution is still working with border! Since I am using GStreamer in a demo I am still considering to write specific code or to keep the border for this demo.

Comment: That indeed works for the video size. For a demo this should be more than ok. Keep in mind that you are doing video scaling in software which can be more expensive than running on the original resolution but scaling the window - in which case most likely the GPU will do the scaling (depending on the renderer being used).